# Python exchangelib Retrieving Sent Subject Line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass through exchangelib MS365 and retrieve my sent folders subject line. The below code works easily with `account.inbox` however it does not work with `account.sent`.
Any Ideas:

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials

creds = Credentials(username='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                    , password='XXXXXXXXXXX')

account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    credentials=creds, 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE)

#for item in account.sent.all()[:5]:
#        print(item.subject)


z = account.sent.all()
print([t for t in z[:5]])
```

Comment: This should work for all folders. What is the error you're getting?